# Selector - Selecting all tables on a page in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have multiple tables (no IDs or names) on a page at various levels within embedded divs.  What would my selector be (if it is possible) to select all tables regardless of where it resides on a page and iterate or filter the tables based on the content of the first cell in the first row?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/

Comment: Don't just start using a library.  Read the documentation first.  DUH!

Answer (score 13):

You can simply use `$('table')` as your selector.

Then you can use the existing filters such as "`:contains`" or "`:has`", or the `.filter()` function if you need more finegrained control over in filtering your results. For example,

```
$('table:has(td > span)')
```

or

```
$('table').filter(function(index){
  return $(this).html() == "<tr><td>something</td></tr>";
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try...

```
$("table").each(function(){
  var curTable = $(this);
  var cell = $(this).find("tr:first td:first");

  if ($(cell).text() == "some text"){
  }
});
```

alternatively you could all check the html of the first cell in the if clause by $(cell).html()

Answer (score 2):

To select all tables couldn't be simpler:

```
$("table")
```

Adding a filter

```
$("table:has(td:first:contains('mytext'))")
```

Answer (score 2):

This will select all the tables:

```
$("table")
```

This will select the first TD cell of the first row of each table:

```
$("table tr:first td:first")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get every table by just using `jQuery('table')`.  Whether the tables are in various levels or embedded within divs or whatever doesn't change.

To do additional filtering:

```
jQuery('table').filter( function() { ... } );
```

The passed in function will map the table element to `this`, and you would need to return true to keep it in your collection, or false to discard it.

Comment: I was typing nearly the same thing

Comment: you can use $(this).find("td:first") to get at the first tablecell, and then perform filtering logical (return true or false)

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('table').each(function(){
     $(this).find('tr :first')...
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to look at the first cell in the first row of each table you can use:

`$("table tr:first td:first").each(function() { 
    var html = this.innerHTML; 
    /* Iterative logic here */ 
});`

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like `$('table tr:first td:first:containts("whatever")')` to grab the first cell of the first row with specific content.