# Traverse the HTML document

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am using the following code to traverse one forum

```
var formWithTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

var table = formWithTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
{
  var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

The HTML document is as follows:

```
<div>
<table class="inventory sortable" id="listContainer_datatable" summary="Properties of various    threads" title="Properties of various threads">
<thead>
<tr>
...
<tbody id="listContainer_databody">   
<tr id="listContainer_row:0" class="">
<td  class="smallCell" valign="top">

<input  type="checkbox" name="formCBs" value="2161433" id="listContainer_formCBs2161433" title="Add a new message." />
<label for="listContainer_formCBs2161433" id="listContainer_formCBs2161433Label" class="hideoff">

</label>
</td>
...
</table>
</div>
```

However, I do not know that why `document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]` returns "undefined".

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: What does `document.getElementsByTagName("table")` return?

Comment: Also, you really should try using jQuery.

Comment: It returns "undefinted" and the length is also zero.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selector - Selecting all tables on a page in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889433/selector-selecting-all-tables-on-a-page-in-jquery)

Comment: might be because the script is executed before the table is added to the dom. try executing the script on [window.load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload)

Comment: if you make the html proper and use window.load then your script is fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Kvym8/1/

Answer (score 0):

What you really should be using is jQuery. Then [you can just do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889433):

```
$("table")[0]
```

to select the first table of the document. Simple as that.

---

In other news, if that *is* your document, it isn't valid HTML, so Javascript DOM isn't guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is fine, the only problem might be the script is added before the table is added to the dom, that could be the cause of the problem.

The solution is to move the script to window.onload

```
window.onload = function(){
    var formWithTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

    var table = formWithTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
            console.log(cols[j].innerHTML)
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Kvym8/)

Comment: @user2585365 look at the browser console